# How to resize a cv::Mat in order to use it for a Qlabel (My program throws SIGSEV)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have a problem when resizing a cv::Mat and trying to use it for a pixmap in a Qlabel.

If I resize the mat and dont use it for the Qlabel, the program works fine, and if I do not resize the mat and use it for the pixmap with that size, it also works fine. The problem comes when I try to do both at the same time, for any reason I do not understand.

According to the debug, I recieve the SIGSEV here (from my mainWindow to the deepest error):

```
void MainWindow::print_img(const QImage &img)
{
    ui->map->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img.rgbSwapped()));
}

---------
    QImage rgbSwapped() const &
        { return rgbSwapped_helper(); }

---------
res = QImage(d->width, d->height, d->format);

---------

QImage::QImage(int width, int height, Format format)
    : QImage(QSize(width, height), format)

---------

d = QImageData::create(size, format);

---------

d->data  = (uchar *)malloc(d->nbytes);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: where exactly is the exploding the app? in the malloc line??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ yes on the malloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving the map (where i got my image from) from the class variables to the run() function, so I do not have to resize the map.